# How do you create a bind mount in Docker when running with the WSL2 backend?

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2

I tried

- /mnt/d/s/elasticsearch
- /mnt/host/d/s/elasticsearch
- /host_mnt/d/s/elasticsearch

to point to `D:\s\elasticsearch` but all my attempts are yielding path not found.

Note I only have docker installed, no other WSL Distribution is installed.

I also tried to check if there's anything in the `/mnt` folder as follows and it is empty

```
$ docker run --privileged --rm -v /:/mnt -it alpine ls -la /mnt/mnt
total 2
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          2048 May  6 19:43 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           260 May 14 17:16 ..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mount points with WSL are in `/run/desktop/mnt/host/<drivename>` so to mount `d:/s/elasticsearch` use

```
docker run --rm -v /run/desktop/mnt/host/d/s/elasticsearch:/mnt alpine ls /mnt
```