# Cannot mount volume for drive d:\ or e:\ in Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container, docker-desktop

Searched the internet and Stackoverflow for this but had no success

Using Docker for Desktop version 4.12.0 on Windows 10 with WSL2 as the backend.

In the Windows command prompt window, the following works and lists files in c:/data

```
docker run --rm -v c:/data:/target alpine ls /target
```

But none of the following works. /target directory is always empty!

```
docker run --rm -v d:/data:/target alpine ls /target 

docker run --rm -v "d:/data:/target" alpine ls /target

docker run --rm -v "d:/data":/target alpine ls /target 

docker run --rm -v /mnt/d/data:/target alpine ls /target

docker run --rm -v /run/desktop/host/d/data:/target alpine ls /target 

docker run --rm -v "/run/desktop/host/d/data:/target" alpine ls /target
```

However, within the WSL 2 terminal window following works and lists files under /target directory!

```
docker run --rm -v /mnt/d/data:/target alpine ls /target
```

But I want to use Docker Desktop for Windows and use the Windows command prompt. Ultimately, I want to mount volume inside docker-compose.yml.

Some of the above commands seem to have been working for different people based on StackOverflow answers in past. Don't know if it's because of a different version of Docker for Desktop or not clear if they were trying in the WSL2 terminal window or Windows command prompt window.

Answer (score 6):

You are facing a [Microsoft limitation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/334#issuecomment-233062541) regarding Docker volumes:

> "*We support mapping a whole second drive letter, but for now, **not
> portions of it**.* "

---

You have to just mount the complete d drive, as **`d:`**

Other options such as root (`d:\`), or paths (`d:\somefolder`) won't work with the second drive.

In your case, that means doing something like:

```
docker run -it -v d: alpine ls /d/data
```

If that creates an empty d folder inside your container, that means you're hitting permission issues within the drive.

---

Note that even if the issue comment is from 2016, seems like the limitation [*is still kicking in...*](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/334#issuecomment-700440878)

Comment: Thank you for the link and possible reason. In there, it says it creates empty drive d: inside container. The command you posted gives error. Maybe you meant docker run -it -v "/d":/target  alpine ls /target. I am not sure how https://stackoverflow.com/a/61880665/6598413 worked in 2020. Maybe that is from inside WSL terminal? I need to bind host folder into container volume to read data from host folder.

Comment: mmm maybe there's a typo in the spacing....could you check the edit?

Comment: the thing is, that should mount the entire d drive, so if a data folder exists in root, you should be able to do ls alpine/data....

Comment: Edit didn't work. It needs to be docker run -it -v "/d":/target  alpine ls /target

Comment: This post from the link you sent talks about how empty drive is mounted inside the container https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/334#issuecomment-388315150

Comment: Yep, you are right....tried another option, just edited the answer. Anyway, maybe it will be faster to create a symlink from C pointing to D, before running the container?